# How to merge rows without null fields

Tags: mysql

I'm still learning MySQL and I have this table...

| staff_id | Name | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | 8:00am-5:00pm | 9:00am-6:00pm |
| 2 | Steve | 9:00am-6:00pm | 7:00am-4:00pm |

I have managed to split and insert new rows into the same table using scripts like below.

```
INSERT INTO table (staff_id,Name,Monday)
(SELECT staff_id, Name, "8:00am-1:00pm"
        FROM table
        WHERE Monday= "8:00am-5:00pm");

INSERT INTO table (staff_id,Name,Monday)
(SELECT staff_id, Name, "2:00pm-5:00pm"
        FROM table
        WHERE Monday= "8:00am-5:00pm");
...etc...
```

It works but I end up with too many rows(I'm working with thousands of rows).
Is there a way I can get a table like this below using MySQL scripts only?

| staff_id | Name | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | 8:00am-1:00pm | 9:00am-2:00pm |
| 1 | Mark | 2:00pm-5:00pm | 3:00pm-6:00pm |
| 2 | Steve | 9:00am-2:00pm | 7:00am-12:00pm |
| 2 | Steve | 3:00pm-6:00pm | 1:00pm-4:00pm |

other solutions suggest using aggregate functions(MAX) which unfortunately won't work in my case and I can't figure out how to properly use "JOINs" for this purpose.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UPDATE and not INSERT INTO

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable
>     (`staff_id` int, `Name` varchar(5), `Monday` varchar(13), `Tuesday` varchar(13))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO mytable
>     (`staff_id`, `Name`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Mark', '8:00am-5:00pm', '9:00am-6:00pm'),
>     (2, 'Steve', '9:00am-6:00pm', '7:00am-4:00pm')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATe mytable SET Monday = "8:00am-1:00pm"
>
>         WHERE Monday= "8:00am-5:00pm";
> ```

> ```
> UPDATe mytable SET Monday = "8:00am-1:00pm"
>
>         WHERE Monday= "9:00am-6:00pm";
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> staff_id | Name  | Monday        | Tuesday      
> -------: | :---- | :------------ | :------------
>        1 | Mark  | 8:00am-1:00pm | 9:00am-6:00pm
>        2 | Steve | 8:00am-1:00pm | 7:00am-4:00pm
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=154ac09963002a17bd747c2d6bb2e5fa)*

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. it didn't fully solve the problem coz it doesn't add the second row which was split from the initial row. but at-least you pointed me in the right direction. i had to insert the original rows again and run the script with the new values to be updated in the second row. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: your design confused me a bit. because if foun it hard t believe, that you wanted to insert for all staff members a new row